# Express node.js api app.post does work for / but not with /path

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

I am new at Node.js and  trying to make an API that will do CRUD operations in sql server. The problem for me is that I can get the data but cannot post it, and get the error "cant get /". I know there are similar questions about this subject but nothing works for me so I thought maybe my code has different kinds of error. Any help will be appreciated and save my life in a way. Also, this is my first question on stackoverflow, sorry for the possible mistakes..

Here is the **server.js**

```js
const sql = require('mssql');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var port = process.env.port || 5000;
const sqlConfig = require('./connection/connect') 
const app = express();

app.use(express.json()); // json desteklemesi için
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 


app.get("/test", (req, res, next) => {
    new sql.ConnectionPool(sqlConfig).connect()
        .then(pool => {
            return pool.query('select * from tblProfile')
        })
        .then(result => {
            res.send(result);
        })

})
app.post('/test', (req, res) => {
    let name = req.query.name;
    let lastname = req.query.lastname;
    let email = req.query.email;
    let password = req.query.password;
    let sql = "INSERT INTO tblProfile(name,lastname,email,password) VALUES(? ? ? ?)";
    conn.query(sql, [name, lastname, email, password], (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.write("inserted.");
        res.end();
    });

    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log("working: " + port)
    })
});
```

This is the **connect.js**

```js
   

var sqlConfig = {

    server: '192.168.1.2',
    database: 'profile',
    user: 'username',
    password: 'user',

};

module.exports = sqlConfig;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you aren't responding or sending anything to that route

So if you want to get rid of the error
Run

```
app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
   res.send('hello world')
}
```

But if you want to send a static file to the route
Create a folder call public * note it can be anything

And type

```
var path = require('path');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Then you can access code in the dir

And as for the writing I think you should try this

```
app.post('/test', (req, res) => {
    let name = req.body.name;
    let lastname = req.body.lastname;
    let email = req.body.email;
    let password = req.body.password;
    let sql = "INSERT INTO tblProfile(name,lastname,email,password VAUES(? ? ? ?)";
    conn.query(sql, [name, lastname, email, password], (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.write("inserted.");
        res.end();
    });
```

Change query to body
Since you installed body-parser

Comment: You don't install the `path` module.  It's built-in to nodejs.

Comment: @Ogoh.cyril Hi, thanks for your effort,appreciate it. For the body-parser part you did,I correct it. What I want to do is that post data to the database, I can get but not post it, where should I add the code you specified in the first part? Should I changed the get method completely? Sorry if the question is silly..

Comment: No just adding the first method has nothing to do with your post route ----- can you comment your <form> tags

Comment: Hello,I solved the problem using the first solution you stated and changed the queries little bit. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Taking a quick look over your code, the only issues I can see are in your query to submit the data.  Within your query statement, I added a closed parentheses after the variables to be entered into the database and made a typo correction to the word Values.  I also changed up how the data is retrieved from req.query to destructure it and simply the code a bit.  Based on everything else I saw, and the fact that you are able to get data from the database, this should work out fine. If it doesn't, I would recommend inserting some `console.log()` statements in the post query to see where it might be having issues and why. For example, you could run `console.dir(req.query);` in your post route to see what data is actually coming from the req and make sure it is all there.  If something is missing, then the query won't actually execute.  If this doesn't work, let me know, along with the information from any console logs you did and I'll take another look at it.

```js
const sql = require('mssql');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var port = process.env.port || 5000;
const sqlConfig = require('./connection/connect') 
const app = express();

app.use(express.json()); // json desteklemesi için
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 


app.get("/test", (req, res, next) => {
    new sql.ConnectionPool(sqlConfig).connect()
        .then(pool => {
            return pool.query('select * from tblProfile')
        })
        .then(result => {
            res.send(result);
        })

})
app.post('/test', (req, res) => {
    //console.dir(req.query);
    let {name, lastname, email, password} = req.query;
    let sql = "INSERT INTO tblProfile(name,lastname,email,password) VALUES(? ? ? ?)";
    conn.query(sql, [name, lastname, email, password], (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.write("inserted.");
        res.end();
    });

    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log("working: " + port)
    })
});
```

Comment: Hi,thank you for your respond. As you said, I wrote the console.dir(req.query) but got no response. Also, I realized that I couldn't get the any name,lastname,email or password in console too. I send the data from postman, but cannot get anything.Still no problem about getting data by using app.get. Does this means the data does not come to the node.js? May be the problem about the postman? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, if you are not able to output any data to the console, that means their is nothing in the `req.query`.  Try running a `console.dir(req)` to see what that provides.  If you are successfully sending data to this post route, something should appear in the console from the req.  It might be like Ogoh.cyril stated in his answer where the data is actually in `req.body`.  Either way, please add your code that you are using to call the `app.post` route to the original question so we have a better idea of how you are sending the data.